# Create a computed column based on another column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, formatting, auto-increment

I have a 2 columns in my table: a `varchar(8)` and an `int`.

I want to `auto-increment` the `int column` and when I do, I want to copy the value into the `varchar(8) column`, but pad it with 0's until it is 8 characters long, so for example, if the `int column` was incremented to `3`, the `varchar(8)` column would contain `'00000003'`.

My two questions are, what happens when the `varchar(8)` column gets to `'99999999'` because I don't want to have duplicates?

How would I do this in MySQL?

If my values can be between `00000000` to `99999999`, how many values can i have before I run out?

This is my alternative approach to just creating a random 8 character string and checking MySQL for duplicates. I thought this was a better approach and would allow for a greater number of values.

Answer (score 5):

Because your formatted column depends upon, and is derivable from, the id column, your table design violates [3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).

Either create a view that has your derived column in it (see this in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bdcb/1)):

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS
SELECT *, substring(cast(100000000 + id AS CHAR(9)), 2) AS formatted_id
FROM mytable
```

or just start your auto-increment at `10000000`, then it will always be 8 digits long:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000000;
```

Comment: I need one column to be a varchar(8) and it is my understanding that you can't auto-increment an INT, so I thought the next best solution would be to auto-increment another int field and the left pad the varchar field with 0's until 8 characters long.  I also thhought between `00000000` and `99999999`, I should get a wide range of numbers?

Comment: Right. More generally, you shouldn't have two columns that represent the same physical data. Either use the `int` as your key and if you really need a string-representation of the value, create it in your presentation layer; or, use the `varchar(8)` version as your primary key and do away with the `int`.

Comment: When a record is inserted into the table, a trigger is fired which passes xml data with the varchar(8) column to another system, so that is why I need the varchar(8).  Would another option be to CAST the auto-incremented INT to a varchar(8) in the xml? If this is possible, I guess this would avoid having two fields represent the same value.

Comment: But if I start the auto-increment at 0, then I will get more values than if I just started it at 10000000?

Comment: You only get 10% less values - you still get `10000000-99999999`. Even then, if you exceed 99999999, the number will roll over to a 9-digit number and you're hosed. So I image you must be expecting a lot less than 99999999 inserts, so 10% less probably isn't going to be a problem. The gain is simplicity - always a good thing.

Comment: Only 10%, seemed like it would be more, is there way I can start the auto-increment directly in the create table instead of in alter table.  Here is my example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac8d7/1/0

Comment: Also, is is possible to CAST or CONVERT into a VARCHR(8)?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to cast to varchar in mysql. But do you need that? You want exactly 8 characters, so char(8) is OK. Also I doubt there is an application language that distinguishes char() from varchar(). I can't see why char() would not work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, if the column is unique, it will throw an exception telling that the value already  do exists. But if not unique, after `99999999` you'll get error message that the value is truncated.

Alternatives, why not use `INT AUTO_INCREMENT`? or a custom ID with a combination of date/time, eg

```
YYMMDD-00000
```

This will have a maximum record of 99999 records per day. It will reset on the next day.

Comment: How would I do it in MySQL and how many values are available to me between `00000000` to `99999999`?

Comment: `between 00000000 to 99999999` ==> 100000000 records all in all including 00000000.

Comment: I need one of the columns to be a varchar(8), otherwise I would just use the INT.