# how to add prefix to identity column in mysql.?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Here i am trying to auto increase my identity column in mysql databse like the following with a prefix adding before the number.

**Id------------------Category**

Cat10001---------Men
Cat10002--------Women
Cat10003---------Kids

here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177584/sqlserver-identity-column-with-text) which i referred to do so but i got hung up with an error

**Error:**
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS 'ABCD-' + CAST(Id as varchar(16)) )' at line 4`

**MySql Query:**

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    categoryid AS 'cat' + CAST(Id as varchar(16)) 
)
```

Note: i am using PhpMyadmin mysql.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support calculated columns. Create a view instead.

Comment: what is a view can you please give a small explanation so that i can carry on with that..!!

Comment: [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use BEFORE INSERT trigger. You can do something like this. Check below to see if this is what you needed.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    categoryid varchar(16),
    categoryname varchar(16)
);

CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON MyTable
  FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.categoryid = 
  CONCAT("CAT",COALESCE((SELECT MAX(Id)+1 from MyTable),1));

insert into MyTable(categoryid,categoryname) Values(1,"test");
insert into MyTable(categoryid,categoryname) Values(2,"test1");
```

Comment: what ever you did is right but i want categoryid as primarykey but here ID is primary key when i try to make categoryid as primarykey and ID remain same as AUTO_INCREMENT,it is throwing an error can you please help me how to make category id as primary key?

Comment: You can only define a column as AUTO_INCREMENT if it is a PRIMARY KEY. you can make the categoryid as unique, if it best fits your needs. Look here for a brief explanation - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844899/difference-between-key-primary-key-unique-key-and-index-in-mysql/3844913#3844913

Comment: primarykey in this table will become foreign key in other table.can i make a unique key coloumn as foreign key in other table?

Answer (score 0):

Create a view or a separate table to have this type of data. Like

```
create view calculateddata
as
select Id,
concat('cat',CAST(Id as varchar(16))) AS categoryid
from MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't support calculated columns so a view will be required instead.

You should really read the answer here: [Create a computed column based on another column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16464869/create-a-computed-column-based-on-another-column-in-mysql)

```
CREATE VIEW your_view
  AS
SELECT Concat('CAT', Cast(Id As varchar(11))) As Id
     , categoryid
FROM   MyTable
```